# Touch event for UITabBar or rather UITabBarItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tabbar

How can i set up some kind of touch event for my `UITabBarItem`?

For Buttons there's `buttonname.TouchUpInside`, but what do i need to use for the `UITabBarItem`?

My situation:

I have a `UIView` with a `UITabBar` on it. I now want to do stuff when the user touches one of the `UITabBarItems`.

Comment: UITabBar would be having own delegate method that you can use which item is getting selected.

Comment: Thank you to both SushiHangover and Vishal that was really helpfull! I cant mark both answers as answer (for whatever reason). But thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UITabBar` itself responds to touches and then you look at the `UITabBarItemEventArgs.Item` for the details of the item that was selected in the tab bar and react as needed:

```
var tabBar = new UITabBar();
tabBar.ItemSelected += (object sender, UITabBarItemEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Item} has selected");
    if (e.Item.Tag == 99)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item with tag 99 was selected");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign tag value to `UITabBarItems` and use this method for accessing touch on `UITabBarItem`:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    switch (item.tag) {
        case 0:
            //
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```